# Jenkins: Tests running without displaying the GUI

Tags: ruby, jenkins, automated-tests

Jobs are running and doing well, but it does not open the browser and does not show the steps that are being performed and consequently does not evidence the steps.

**Attempts:**

- Already enabled Allow the service to interact with the desktop
- I've reinstalled Jenkisn with WAR
- I have already changed the service account;
- I have already tested the job manually and the path is correct.
- I already tested on another server and the result is the same.
- Allow service to interact with desktop
- No errors in console

**Settings:**

S.O: Windows Server 2012 R2
Jenkins 2.89.3
Java Updated

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this might be what you are experiencing.  Worth a shot...

You have allowed the Jenkins service to interact with the desktop.  That means that the service is interacting with the desktop in something called "Session 0".

Have you started the "Interactive Services Detection" service?  In order to see activity in a windows service, after XP it is not enough to allow the service to interact with the desktop.  The activity is switched to a completely separate session as a security measure (since windows running as a service typically have very high privileges).  This is called "Session 0".

To see that 'session 0', you will need to start the Interactive Service Detection" service.  Otherwise, the session is completely hidden.  In W2012R2, this service is disabled by default, you will have to change registry key 'NoInteractiveServices' from 1 to 0 in hive HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows or the service will fail to start with a cryptic message like "incorrect function".

Once the Interactive Service Detection service is running, activity in session 0 will cause a pop-up to appear in your own desktop session; the popup will have a 'region' that will switch your screen to the session 0 screen.  The session 0 screen will be pretty blank - it will not have a desktop like you are used to seeing.  It will have a button to switch you back to your own desktop.  Get in and get out quickly - many corporate systems have a timeout that will log you out after a minute or two (not just switch you back.  SO annoying!

A "DOS" command to switch to session 0 if you don't have the popup is 'rundll32 winsta.dll,WinStationSwitchToServicesSession'.  But, the Interactive Services Daemon service does have to be running.

I hope it turns out to be this simple!